# allow anonymous access to .well-known directory

Tags: asp.net, web-config, openid-connect, aspnet-contrib

please bear with me: i am pretty new to all of this

i am working on integrating openid connect with a pair of applications developed by the company.

we are using custom/company specific openid connect libraries that are, i think, essentially wrappers around Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect and Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

in the idP application web.config, we have something like:

```
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <authentication mode="Forms">
        <forms loginUrl="~/Login" name="{....}" protection="All" path="/" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="false" defaultUrl="~/Home" cookieless="UseCookies" />
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
        <!-- denies anonymous users to all pages, except those defined under location nodes -->
    </authorization>
</location>
```

plus a bunch of location nodes to allow/deny access to specific pages/resources

the problem is that when the openid connect stuff tries to access /.well-known/openid-configuration when the user is not logged in (or, it seems in the process of logging in),
the response is a 302 redirect to the login page

obviously this is causing problems when a JSON response is expected

i have tried adding a location node to the web.config:

```
<location path= "~/.well-known/openid-configuration">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

(i also tried with path = "~/.well-known")

but i am still getting redirected to the login page

to be clear, there is no actual directory /.well-known in the idP application; the file seems to be constructed somewhere in Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the file seems to be constructed somewhere in Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server

Yes, it is.

Try calling `app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate)` immediately after registering the OIDC server middleware to prevent ASP.NET from applying the authorization policies before it has a chance to be invoked:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectServer(options => {
    options.AllowInsecureHttp = true;
});

app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate);
```

Note that you shouldn't need an exception for `~/.well-known/openid-configuration` in your `web.config` when using `app.UseStageMarker()`.

Comment: thank you so much! that worked. as an aside: i end up calling app.UseStageMarker(PipelineStage.Authenticate) after registering the custom middleware that acts as a kind of wrapper for UseOpenIdConnectServer

Comment: Great! I'd love to hear more about how you're using the OIDC server middleware with your custom middleware. If you're willing to share a few details about that, please join me on https://gitter.im/aspnet-contrib/AspNet.Security.OpenIdConnect.Server or https://jabbr.net/#/rooms/aspnet-contrib. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new too but I think you a path to a .aspx page in the location and the rest is inherited.Just change deny to allow users with the asterix. Also make sure the web.config is in the directory. Sounds like you do but in well-known should be the web.config with allow all users.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <location path="Manage.aspx">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: thanks for responding. i can't just change deny to allow, because we actually do want to redirect for most pages. furthermore, as i said, the .well-known directory does not actually exist in the application: as far as i can tell, the middleware should 'intercept' the request and construct the appropriate json for the response